# How to consolidate all rows that have the same date and participant id (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to write a simple mysql migration like script.
My goal is to select participant_id and date and if they = the same -  return a count.
In this example the count would return 4.
I would then take the count and store it in a variable to be placed into another table.
Basically I'm consolidating the data from 4 rows into 1 row in a new table that will have the a count field.

My data currently.

```
ID   PARTICIPANT_ID  DATE  
---  --------------  ---------------------
"1"  "4"             "2015-05-06 21:35:37"
"2"  "4"             "2015-05-06 21:35:37"
"3"  "4"             "2015-05-06 21:35:37"
"4"  "4"             "2015-05-06 21:35:37"
```

My goal.

```
ID    PARTICIPANT_ID  DATE                   COUNT  
----  --------------  ---------------------  -----
"1"   "4"             "2015-05-06 21:35:37"  "4"
```

I've attempted writing a query like this:

```
SELECT ID, PARTICIPANT_ID, DATE FROM mytable
```

What changes do I need to make to my query to return the specified resultset?

Comment: why id =1 in result?

Comment: The id field is a auto increment field.

Comment: the question was why in result set it is 1 but not 2 or 3 or 4?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable

Answer (score 1):

Here's one (of several alternatives) that will return the specified result.

```
SELECT MIN(t.id) AS id
     , t.participant_id
     , t.date
     , COUNT(*) AS `count`
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.participant_id, t.date
```

The "trick" is the `GROUP BY` clause. That "collapses" all rows with common values for the listed expressions into a single row.  The `COUNT(*)` aggregate function returns a count of rows that were "collapsed" into the `GROUP`. The `MIN(t.id)` aggregate returns the lowest value of the `id` column from rows in the group.

Comment: Perfect this was exactly what I needed. This collapsed all my data into 1 row that has a count of 4. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
select null, PARTICIPANT_ID, DATE, COUNT(*) from TABLE1
GROUP BY null, PARTICIPANT_ID, DATE
```

when ID-Field ist AUTOINCREMENT in TABLE2 he should set it correkt.

TIP: Don't name your columns "date" or "count" because these names CAN be keywords and you will get some trouble later.

Comment: That's good advice, about avoiding [MySQL Reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as identifiers (table names and column names). We can avoid a lot of the problems by *qualifying* the column references with table name or (preferably) table alias.  e.g.  `t.reservedword`, or in places we can't qualify the reference, by enclosing the reference in backticks. (We can also use double quotes around identifiers, for compatibility with other RDBMS (e.g. Oracle), if we include `ANSI_QUOTES` in the `sql_mode` setting for the session.)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is only the first column `id` but you can do `MIN(id)` or `MAX(id)` if need.

```
SELECT participant_id, `date`, CONT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY participant_id, `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT participant_id,date,count(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY participant_id, date
```